# ngClass Not working on activating class with click?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to show activated class as active but It's not working It goes to that class for half a sec and comes back, I have tried something like this.

```
 <ion-row   >


        <ion-col  col-3 (click)="deviceType('Light')" ><div class="circle-text " [ngClass]="{'active-class': (selectedItem == 'Light')}"><div class="circle-inside"><ion-icon name="custom-icon-lights"></ion-icon></div></div><div class="circle-head-txt">Lights</div></ion-col>
        <ion-col col-3 (click)="deviceType('Ac')"><div class="circle-text" [ngClass]="{'active-class': (selectedItem == 'Ac')}"><div class="circle-inside"><ion-icon name="custom-icon-ac"></ion-icon></div></div><div class="circle-head-txt">AC</div></ion-col>
        <ion-col col-3 (click)="deviceType('Sensor')"><div class="circle-text" [ngClass]="{'active-class': (selectedItem == 'Sensor')}"><div class="circle-inside"><ion-icon name="custom-icon-humidity"></ion-icon></div></div><div class="circle-head-txt">Sensors</div></ion-col>
        <ion-col  col-3 (click)="deviceType('Camera')"><div class="circle-text" [ngClass]="{'active-class': (selectedItem == 'Camera')}"><div class="circle-inside"><ion-icon name="custom-icon-camera"></ion-icon></div></div><div class="circle-head-txt">Camera</div></ion-col>

 </ion-row>
```

this is My .ts file I am setting selectedItem  by default to Light

```
  deviceType(type: string) {
    this.selectedItem = type;

    if(type == "Light"){
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(LightPage);
    }else if(type == "Sensor"){
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(SensorsPage);
    } else if(type == "Camera"){
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(CameraPage);
    }else if(type == "Ac"){
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(AcPage);
    }else if(type == "Rgb"){
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(RbglightPage);
    }else if(type == "Fan"){
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(FanPage);
    }else if(type == "Curtain"){
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(CurtainPage);
    }
    else {

        this.deviceTypeChild.emit(type);
    }


  }
```

this is scss file

```
  .active-class:after {
    background: #dbdff1!important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do another way

```
[class.active-class]="selectedItem == 'Light'"
```